# How to copy from a dataframe only all fields associated with a specific user_id to another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe df which contains table as below :

```
timestamp   user_id val1    val2     val3  val4    val5    val6
01/01/2011  1   100 3    5     100     3       5
01/02/2013  1   8        6     12      15      3
01/07/2012  1   19  57   10    9       6       6        
01/11/2014  3   49  6        12    15      3
21/12/2012  3       240  30    240     30       
01/12/2013  3       63                  
01/12/2013  5   51  63       50
```

I would to know how I can copy only all fields associated with a specific user_id to another dataframe df1, for example obtain a table as below :

```
timestamp   user_id val1    val2     val3  val4    val5    val6
01/01/2011  1   100 3    5     100     3       5
01/02/2013  1   8        6     12      15      3
01/07/2012  1   19  57   10    9       6       6
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`df['user_id'] == 1` would return a boolean array which is True when the value in the `user_id` column equals 1. Therefore, you could select those rows with

```
df.loc[df['user_id'] == 1]
```

---

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
    timestamp  user_id  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6
0  01/01/2011        1   100     3     5   100     3     5
1  01/02/2013        1     8     6    12    15     3   NaN
2  01/07/2012        1    19    57    10     9     6     6
3  01/11/2014        3    49     6    12    15     3   NaN
4  21/12/2012        3   240    30   240    30   NaN   NaN
5  01/12/2013        3    63   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
6  01/12/2013        5    51    63    50   NaN   NaN   NaN

[7 rows x 8 columns]

In [9]: df['user_id'] == 1
Out[9]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
Name: user_id, dtype: bool    

In [11]: df.loc[df['user_id'] == 1]
Out[11]: 
    timestamp  user_id  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6
0  01/01/2011        1   100     3     5   100     3     5
1  01/02/2013        1     8     6    12    15     3   NaN
2  01/07/2012        1    19    57    10     9     6     6

[3 rows x 8 columns]
```

---

`df[df['user_id'] == 1]` also works, but I think it is less clear since it uses the same syntax as you would use to select columns.

---

Here is how I re-constructed the DataFrame `df` based on the table you posted. I've edited the data to include commas in the `user_id` column, to simulate your actual data. I saved

```
timestamp   user_id val1    val2     val3  val4    val5    val6
01/01/2011  1   100 3    5     100     3       5
01/02/2013  1   8        6     12      15      3
01/07/2012  1   19  57   10    9       6       6        
01/11/2014  3   49  6        12    15      3
21/12/2012  3       240  30    240     30       
01/12/2013  3       63                  
01/12/2013  1,500   51  63       50
```

in a file called `data` and then ran

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')  # Set a locale which uses commas as the separator
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+', converters={u'user_id':locale.atoi})
```

Comment: It seems to not work when I use a variable in a code such as n=1, df['user_id'] == n .

Comment: For an unknown reason, even df[df['user_id'] == 1] does not work for me.

Comment: Well, the only thing that comes to mind for why it might not work is if your `user_id` column is storing strings instead of ints. You can test if this is true by looking at `df['user_id'].dtype`. It should be something like `dtype('int64')`. If that is the source of the problem then you need to revise the way your are constructing `df`. If that is not the source of the problem, then please post runnable code which reproduces the problem. "Does not work for me" is generally not sufficient information for us to help you.

Comment: The output is dtype(O). They are objects.

Comment: Then a quick but less-than-ideal fix would be to convert `user_id` to `int` dtype:  `df['user_id'] = df['user_id'].astype('int')`. However, that is just patching over the problem. A better solution would be to construct `df` to have the right dtype from the very beginning. If you are reading the data in from a text file, then you may be able to construct the desired `df` using `pd.read_table` as shown above. Otherwise, if you'd like suggestions on how to construct `df` properly, you'd have to give more details (and code) showing how you are currently constructing `df`.

Comment: Alternatively, another less-than-ideal solution would be to use `df.loc[df['user_id'] == "1"]` (note the quotation marks around the `1`), but that is obviously an ugly workaround if the `user_id` is supposed to be ints.

Comment: How did you save the file to data?Using to_csv or something else?

Comment: Originally I take the data from a csv file where some user_id have values as 1,300.

Comment: When I try to convert the field 'user_id' to int, using df[['user_id']] = df[['user_id']].astype(int), I receive the error message 'invalid literal for long() with base 10'.

Comment: I've added some code above showing how to parse the data into a DataFrame which converts `user_ids` like `1,500` into the `int`, `1500`.